# Changing screen contents by clicking a specific tab

Tags: flutter, dart, tabs, tabbar, tabbarcontroller

I am using a TabBar in the middle of my screen, there are 4 tabs. I want to change the content above the tabbar when I click on the 3rd tab.
for the first 2 tabs I want to show a text with a searchbar and when I click the 3rd or 4th tab I want to replace the text and the searchbar to another text and a row of Weekdays.
[This is the content I am showing (currently) for all the tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51NoL.png)
[This is what I want to show when I click the "To Do" or the "Blog" tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psMiU.png)

As I am new to Flutter, I have been working for months with the frontend and haven't faced such an issue. so I haven't tried anything.

[Here is the main screen where I am displaying the Text and the SearchBar, works fine for the first 2 tabs but I want to change the text and the Searchbar when for the rest of 2 tabs (To Do & Blogs tabs)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6byTT.png)

[This is the TabBar with the Tabs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTQRb.png)

Comment: Use TabBar to achieve to achieve this UI. And Modify TabBar's indicator prop

Comment: Can you include sample code-snippet that will reproduce the same error

Comment: Please have a look at the code-snippets of the screen and the TabBar. your replies are highly appreciated. Thanks you so much

Comment: Please do not include code in images. Include well-formatted code in your question to get useful ansewers.

Comment: Thank you Ber, the issue was solved using custom enums.